# pytesseract и распознавание одного символа на python

Tags: python, tesseract

Пишу в качестве своей первой настоящей работы покерный индикатор. Задача сейчас считывать карты со стола.
Использую для этого tesseract. Тестировал его с "Банк" на столе(т.е. считывает какое количество денег сейчас в банке) и он прилично справляется с задачей, хотя не без косяков, нужна тонкая настройка. Но с картами проблема. Изначально задумка была простой - считываем с помощью тессеракта номинал карты, а с помощью cv2 цвет и таким образом получаем каждую карту. Но тессеракт оказывается считывать по одному символу. Пробовал ему скормить со всеми различным конфигами всю доску(5 карт на столе), он частично только читает что-то. Из бубна - менял стиль карт, делал скрины чб, увеличивал/уменьшал изображения, пробовал все конфиги(в т.ч. забивал считывание только цифр), даже продублировал скрин, что бы он думал что это две-три цифры/буквы(через раз считывал). Особая проблема с "10" он её категорически отказывается понимать. Но все же хотелось бы именно по одной карте считывать. В качестве испытуемого покерстарс.
Вопрос, кто как попробовал бы это реализовать или у кого есть готовое решение? Не стоит забывать, что работа должна выполняться очень быстро, менее 0.30сек или около того, потому тяжелые библиотеки не рассматривал.
Дедлайна у меня нету, для себя, но мозги уже вскипели, помогите пж.

Добавил для наглядности картинку, минус яркость, + контраст, не читает все равно.
[image: Пример]

Дополняю, пока жду ответов, попробовал изменить цвет фона на белый, а текст черный, к моему удивлению даже проблемная Q - она же дама распозналась. Но проблема с "10" остается актуальной еще, ибо он её переводит как "ID"

Comment: Ну tesseract не настроен же считывать пиксели с экрана. Он настроен считывать сканированные документы. Увеличьте размер картинки в 10-20 раз, уменьшите яркость, увеличьте контраст. Тогда, может быть прочитает. А сейчас над вашей `"10"` tesseract ломает голову точка это или запятая. На кляксах размером 10 пикселей в высоту он никогда не распознает цифры.

Comment: Я же писал, что я увеличивал скриншоты и в 5 раз и в 20. Результаты одинаковые.

Comment: значит вам просто не повезло. попробуйте opecv. там настроек поменьше. глядишь действительно подойдет...